# How can I create a Docker container with a Wordpress image and use the environment variables in gcloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I want to create an instance container with a Wordpress image.

I can create the container with:

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container test-container --container-image=registry.hub.docker.com/library/wordpress --tags=http-server --zone=europe-west1-b --machine-type=n1-standard-1
```

How do I also pass the environment variables of the image?

```
-e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=10.0.0.0
-e WORDPRESS_DB_USER="test"
-e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD="test"
-e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME="test"
-e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX="wp_"
```

Can I do this with a flag in my create-with-container statement and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to the `docker run` command that allows passing environment variables:

```
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
  --env , -e        Set environment variables
  --env-file        Read in a file of environment variables
```

`gcloud compute instances create-with-container` supports similar functionality and command line parameters:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create-with-container INSTANCE_NAMES [INSTANCE_NAMES …]

  --container-env=[KEY=VALUE, …,…]
    Declare environment variables KEY with value VALUE passed to container. 
    Only the last value of KEY is taken when KEY is repeated more than once. 
    Values, declared with --container-env flag override those with the same KEY from file, provided in --container-env-file. 

  --container-env-file=CONTAINER_ENV_FILE
    Declare environment variables in a file. 
    Values, declared with --container-env flag override those with the same KEY from file.
    File with environment variables in format used by docker (almost). This means:
    • Lines are in format KEY=VALUE.
    • Values must contain equality signs.
    • Variables without values are not supported (this is different from docker format).
    • If # is first non-whitespace character in a line the line is ignored as a comment.
    • Lines with nothing but whitespace are ignored.
```

For example

```
CloudShell:$ gcloud compute instances create-with-container nginx-container --container-image gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/nginx1:1.14 --zone=europe-west3-c --tags=nginx --container-env=MYVAR1=myval1,MYVAR2=myval2
```

Alternatively, you may create a shell script like the `create-vm.sh` below:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
gcloud compute instances create-with-container nginx-container --container-image gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/nginx1:1.14 --zone=europe-west3-c --tags=nginx --container-env=MYVAR1=$1,MYVAR2=$2
```

launch it with the variables passed in the command line:

```
CloudShell:$ chmod +x create-vm.sh
CloudShell:$ ./create-vm.sh myval1 myval2
```

then connect via SSH to the newly created VM instance `nginx-container` and check variables within the Docker container:

```
nginx-container:$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE                   COMMAND         CREATED     STATUS  NAMES 
8637cbacf2e1    gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/nginx1:1.14             "/usr/local/bin/dock…"  4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes    klt-nginx-container-ikrz 
nginx-container:$ sudo docker exec 8637cbacf2e1 printenv MYVAR1 MYVAR2
myval1
myval2
```

[Docker Doc > Command-line reference > Docker CLI (docker) > docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

[Developer Tools > Cloud SDK: Command Line Interface > Doc > Reference > gcloud compute instances create-with-container](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create-with-container)

Comment: I tried this also but I'm probably doing it wrong.

I used --container-env=[WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=$1,WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress, WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=test,WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=$2,WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_]

With and without [] en also with ""  and without. I still got the message :ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create-with-container) unrecognized arguments:

Comment: A working example has been added to the answer.